# VBA locked my worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I tried copying some code online that I found from below link...
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=15325

And I attempted to use some code to import an image via button within my Excel Workbook and this code locked my work sheet and when it prompts for a password I tried hitting enter with no prevail...

Code I used below

```
Sub BrowsePicture()
Dim Pict
Dim ImgFileFormat As String
Dim PictCell As Range
Dim Ans As Integer

ActiveSheet.Protect True, True, True, True, True
ImgFileFormat = "Image Files (*.bmp),others, tif (*.tif),*.tif, jpg (*.jpg),*.jpg"

GetPict:
Pict = Application.GetOpenFilename(ImgFileFormat)
'Note you can load in any nearly file format
If Pict = False Then End

Ans = MsgBox("Open : " & Pict, vbYesNo, "Insert Picture")
If Ans = vbNo Then GoTo GetPict

'Now paste to userselected cell
GetCell:
Set PictCell = Application.InputBox("Select the cell to insert into", Type:=8)
If PictCell.Count > 1 Then MsgBox "Select ONE cell only": GoTo GetCell
PictCell.Select
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Pict).Select
End Sub
```

Please help! I put a lot of work into this spread sheet and I can't edit anything :(

Comment: The line `ActiveSheet.Protect True, True, True, True, True` locks the spreadsheet, according to the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protect-method-excel). [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-unprotect-method-excel) also suggests `ActiveSheet.Unprotect` should unlock it, assuming no password was set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first parameter of `ActiveSheet.Protect True, True, True, True, True` is the password, so you have set the password to be `True`. (Note: not `"True"`, the actual value `True`, which you won't be able to type in from the standard unprotect dialog.).

You can unprotect it again by executing the command

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect True
```

from the Immediate Window (or you could write a small Sub to do it).

Comment: You're a savior! Thank you so much!

I thought that's what I did too, and I tried typing it in but it must have taken it as the True flag being the password not the actual word.

I really can't thank you enough!